# How can I change the font size of a label in vaadin in a layout-engine-friendly fashion?

Tags: vaadin

Say I have a label:

```
Label myLabel = new Label(_("I am smaller than normal text"));
myLabel.setSizeUndefined();
```

(where `_` is your favorite localization function).

I'd like it to be smaller than usual. Since there is no ad-hoc Label method for accomplishing this I must resort to adding "raw" CSS rules, for example like so:

```
CSSInject cssSmall = new CSSInject(".small { font-size: small; }");
myPage.addComponent(cssSmall);
myLabel.addStyleName("small");
myPage.addComponent(myLabel);
```

That only sort of works. Yes, the text *is* smaller, but when the page is first built, Vaadin sizes the label as if it the font was regular sized. When something causes the page to be repainted/relaid out, Vaadin realizes what's going on and gives the correct size to the label.

This causes the page to "jump" noticeably as the label becomes both shorter and not as tall.

How can I work around this?

Comment: why not use a theme? you can be sure the styling is there and there should be no vile hickups in the browser.

Comment: @cfrick If using a theme means this doesn't happen then I'll accept it as an answer even if the particular approach isn't available to me

Comment: then maybe put this as an edit in your question (that you can not use themes (why not btw?)), so some valid answer for your problem can be issued

Comment: oh and while you are at it, also add your vaadin version and if this is liferay or not

Comment: @cfrick on mobile right now. Yes we are using liferay and websphere. I can't remember which version of vaadin. We're not writing vaadin projects. The proprietary architecture we are using has one vaadin project that defines one generic portlet and loads the actual code at runtime with spring. We have to write all the plumbing code by hand and there is no obvious way to add our own CSS to the global set of rules. (Also often changes mean a server restart.) Most of the existing code concatenates strings containing HTML fragments together (oh hi XSS).

Comment: Our situation is pretty particular so I'm open to generic answers that are more universally helpful

Answer (score 2):

Since your situation seems desperate and themes are no option you could just wrap the content for the label in HTML (make it a class, if you need it more than once).

It would look something like this (this is Groovy, but it's easy to translate into Java or whatever you are using:

```
new Label("<span style='font-size:small'>${StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4('&somesmalltext')}<span>").with{
    contentMode = ContentMode.HTML
    it
}
```

The key here is to escape your text, wrap it in any HTML, and use the `ContentMode.HTML` for the `Label`.

The "proper" way to handle this would just to have a theme, add your:

```
 .v-label.small { font-size: small }
```

there, and then set the style on your lable:

```
  myLabel.addStyleName("small")
```

Comment: What is the "it" line in the first codeblock about?

Comment: ignore it.  it just returns the label "it"self there.  `with` is some `map` "bastard" in groovy.